# How to build ceylon using the ceylon commandline tools?

Tags: java, ceylon

How can I setup and build the ceylon distribution as a mixed java and ceylon project using only the ceylon commandline tools instead of ant?

I assume having cloned the git repository, cleaned and dist-ed the ant project following the instructions in https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon,  ceylon/dist/README.md, and therefore - among all the other parts - having ready a parser from the grammar using antlr.

Cant you outline the necessary steps, or show a script that collects the required .java and .ceylon files and the resources and .xml files and so on from the git / ant project. Cant you setup one on git hub?

Specificly, what dependencies am I to put where (repo), and how must I handle version strings like ¨1.2.1¨ when working with java dependencies (jars, not cars) in the ceylon project?

For the sake of simplicity I could do with building only the compiler-java and related subprojects, specificly the typechecker, leaving away the compiler-js and its related .js files.

Finally, why is the ceylon distribution built with ant instead of the ceylon tools?

Comment: For the "why": I guess the reason is that this way you don't need to already have the distribution to build the distribution?

Comment: To make the ¨Why¨ of using the ceylon commandline tools understandible, it is simply that I want to keep things understandibly simple. I think it is not necessary to have 324 MB of byte and source code to build a system that does typechecking and compiling in a quite straightforward way (and finally I end up with around 20MB of it).  To make the ¨Why¨ of  the first pass understandible, it is  because the  https://github.com/ceylon/ceylon is simply made so to fetch all the sources and dependencies from where they are and I cant help it.

Comment: Not using ant seems arbitrary to the point of being idiotic.

Comment: By the seventh day Ant had finished the work she had been doing; so on the seventh day she rested from all her work. Build.xml 2:2.

Answer (score 0):

I can only partially answer my own question as far as the the build of the ceylon typechecker is concerned. After generating all the necessary java source files and consolidating the source directories the typechecker was built without errors and could be used without runtime errors.

Speaking for myself this is enough to discard the hypothesis that compiling a java project is an enterprise that never leads to success. In this considerable instance it even led to success at runtime. This is truly amazing.